# Is it possible to keep metaballs symmetric?

Tags: modeling, meta-objects, metaballs

When I model animals or humanoid species, mostly I use metaballs to create the base mass of the mesh. I love metaballs, it's easy to create a good proxy mesh from them. But I don't know how to keep them symmetrical. Is there a way to do this, similar to Mirror modifier or the symmetry mode of sculpting mode? For example a python script that can maintain symmetry of certain object-pairs while modeling.

[image]

Comment: You can try to sketch by duplicating and scaling icospheres in edit mode and add Remesh modifier and Mirror modifier ... It works in a similar way (⁠•⁠‿⁠•⁠)

Comment: This is a workaround, but very good idea and works surpisingly well!

Comment: The main problem with it is that the element tension is not modifiable, negative field is not possible, and if I increment voxel density, the surface becomes sharp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As mentioned - not possible without some python ...*

---

Some way can be to ...

- model one side
- *Duplicate* without "mother" object (an object without a number .00x)
- with duplicated objects still selected, add to active one *Constraints* > **Copy Location** > *X* and *Invert X*
- choose operator Copy modifiers to Selected
  (repeat same for **Copy Scale** constraint)

The tedious part here is to set manually target for each objet.

[image]

Comment: This seems to be the best technique without scripting. And if I duplicate a symmetrised object together with its pair, the copies will keep the ther constrain relations. I tried it, works very good!

Comment: Nice. Hopefully someone makes an addon for this, or even Blender gets builtin metaball mirroring.